# Keep stuck at the reading the data from database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-access

I would like to minus the data from the database with the value that I give when I run the program. Everything works, but I keep stuck at the `newVal`. I already did it like this, but the `newVal` keep appear `0` (because I declared `decimal newVal = 0`, but on this question, I just used `decimal newVal;`). Two more problems: if I move the `newVal = ...` to the top, it is useless, because one of the calculations in the `newVal` is reading data from the database (since I want database minus with the new value given when i run the program, required `dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`), but if I put the `newVal` at the bottom after reading data, it is useless as well, because I set the `Quantity = ?` and the value of `?` is `newVal..` Well, here is the code:

```
private void AddObjects(object sender, EventArgs e, Form theForm)
{
    button1.Visible = true;

    textBoxQuantityContainer = new List<NumericUpDown>();
    textBoxCodeContainer = new List<NumericTextBox>();
    textBoxDescContainer = new List<TextBox>();
    textBoxSubTotalContainer = new List<TextBox>();
    textBoxTotalContainer = new List<TextBox>();
    textBoxAllTotalContainer = new TextBox();

    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Code] FROM [Seranne]", conn);

    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    AutoCompleteStringCollection codesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    while (dReader.Read())
    {
        string numString = dReader[0].ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
        codesCollection.Add(numString);
    }

    dReader.Close();
    conn.Close();

    if (firstForm.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        label1.Text = "Code:";
        label1.Location = new Point(60, 125);
        label2.Text = "Welcome to the Selling System.";
        label2.Location = new Point(600, 30);
        label3.Text = "Quantity:";
        label3.Location = new Point(155, 125);
        label4.Text = "Description:";
        label4.Location = new Point(580, 125);
        label5.Text = "Sub Total on Rp:";
        label5.Location = new Point(1020, 125);
        label6.Text = "Total on Rp:";
        label6.Location = new Point(1210, 125);
        label7.Text = "Total on Rp:";
        label7.Location = new Point(1080, 580);
    }

    else if (firstForm.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        label1.Text = "Kode:";
        label1.Location = new Point(60, 125);
        label2.Text = "Selamat datang di Selling System.";
        label2.Location = new Point(600, 30);
        label3.Text = "Banyaknya:";
        label3.Location = new Point(145, 125);
        label4.Text = "Keterangan:";
        label4.Location = new Point(580, 125);
        label5.Text = "Sub Total di Rp:";
        label5.Location = new Point(1020, 125);
        label6.Text = "Total di Rp:";
        label6.Location = new Point(1210, 125);
        label7.Text = "Total di Rp:";
        label7.Location = new Point(1080, 580);
    }

    //****TextBox for Code****
    for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
    {
        textBoxCodeContainer.Add(new NumericTextBox());
        textBoxCodeContainer[y].Size = new Size(100, 50);
        textBoxCodeContainer[y].Location = new Point(25, 150 + (y * 25));
        textBoxCodeContainer[y].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);

        textBoxCodeContainer[y].AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBoxCodeContainer[y].AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBoxCodeContainer[y].AutoCompleteCustomSource = codesCollection;

        theForm.Controls.Add(textBoxCodeContainer[y]);
    }

    //****TextBox for Quantity****
    for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
    {
        textBoxQuantityContainer.Add(new NumericUpDown());
        textBoxQuantityContainer[y].Size = new Size(100, 50);
        textBoxQuantityContainer[y].Location = new Point(125, 150 + (y * 25));
        textBoxQuantityContainer[y].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
        textBoxQuantityContainer[y].Maximum = 1000;

        theForm.Controls.Add(textBoxQuantityContainer[y]);
    }

    //****TextBox for Description****
    for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
    {
        textBoxDescContainer.Add(new TextBox());
        textBoxDescContainer[y].Size = new Size(750, 50);
        textBoxDescContainer[y].Location = new Point(225, 150 + (y * 25));

        theForm.Controls.Add(textBoxDescContainer[y]);
    }

    //****TextBox for Sub Total****
    for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
    {
        textBoxSubTotalContainer.Add(new TextBox());
        textBoxSubTotalContainer[y].Size = new Size(175, 50);
        textBoxSubTotalContainer[y].Location = new Point(975, 150 + (y * 25));

        theForm.Controls.Add(textBoxSubTotalContainer[y]);
    }

    //****TextBox for Total****
    for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
    {
        textBoxTotalContainer.Add(new TextBox());
        textBoxTotalContainer[y].Size = new Size(175, 50);
        textBoxTotalContainer[y].Location = new Point(1150, 150 + (y * 25));
        textBoxTotalContainer[y].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);

        theForm.Controls.Add(textBoxTotalContainer[y]);
    }

    //****TextBox for Total All****
    textBoxAllTotalContainer.Size = new Size(175, 50);
    textBoxAllTotalContainer.Location = new Point(1150, 575);
    textBoxAllTotalContainer.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);

    theForm.Controls.Add(textBoxAllTotalContainer);
}

private void UpdateDatas()
{
    int codeValue = 0;
    int index = 0;

    string query = "SELECT [Quantity], [Description], [Price] FROM [Seranne] WHERE [Code] IN (";

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    conn.Open();

    if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0].Text, out codeValue))
    {
        query = query + codeValue.ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[i].Text, out codeValue))
        {
            query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
        }
    }

    query = query + ")";

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

    OleDbDataReader dReader;

    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dReader.Read())
    {
        if (textBoxCodeContainer[index].TextLength != 0)
        {
            this.textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(dReader["Quantity"].ToString());
            this.textBoxDescContainer[index].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
            this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[index].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
        }

        index += 1;
    }

    dReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}

private void UpdatePrice()
{
    int totalPrice = 0;
    int quantity = 0;
    int price = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        if (textBoxQuantityContainer[i].Value > 0)
        {
            quantity = (int)textBoxQuantityContainer[i].Value;
            price = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSubTotalContainer[i].Text);
            textBoxTotalContainer[i].Text = (quantity * price).ToString();
        }

        else
        {
            textBoxSubTotalContainer[i].Text = "";
            textBoxTotalContainer[i].Text = "";
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        if (textBoxTotalContainer[i].TextLength != 0)
        {
            totalPrice += Convert.ToInt32(textBoxTotalContainer[i].Text);
        }
    }

    textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = totalPrice.ToString("n2");
}

private void UpdateQuantity()
{
    int index = 0;
    int codeValue = 0;
    decimal newVal;         

    List<int> integers = new List<int>();

    foreach (var tb in textBoxCodeContainer)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out codeValue))
        {
            integers.Add(codeValue);
        }
    }

    string command = "UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity]=? WHERE [Code] IN(" + string.Join(", ", integers) + ")";

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
    cmd.Parameters["Quantity"].Value = this.newVal.ToString();

    OleDbDataReader dReader;

    conn.Open();

    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dReader.Read())
    {
        if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0)
        {
            newVal = (Convert.ToInt32(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()) -
    textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value);

            int numberOfRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        index += 1;
    }

    if (newVal == 0)
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
        sounds.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Update", "Error");
    }

    else
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
        sound.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("Was Updated Successfully", "Success");
    }

    dReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}

private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDatas();
    UpdatePrice();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateQuantity();
}
```

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Can you tell me why you compare these fields?  `textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >=
    Convert.ToInt32(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()` The quantity can only grow?

Comment: Hi @JeroenvanLangen: question that you ask already answered by me, in your answer comments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good day, i got several things here:

1) `cmd.Parameters["Quantity"].Value = this.newVal.ToString();` conversion to string is not needed here, because the Value is an object. You already defined that it should be handled as integer.

2) Replace the `?` within you query to `@Quantity`, so it will be filled by the query execution.

3) When updating you don't need to execute it as a reader. use the `int numberOfRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` without the loop. It will update all items.

4) You should execute the `if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0 && textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >=
    Convert.ToInt32(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()))
        {` when building the integers list, this way you are only updating the right quantities.

If you only want to update certain rows, you'll have to expand your where clause:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("MinimumQuantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = minimumQuantity;

string command = "UPDATE [Seranne] 
                  SET [Quantity]=@Quantity
                  WHERE [Code] IN(" + string.Join(", ", integers) + ")
                  AND [Quantity] > @MinimumQuantity
```

The higest **risk** is: You assume that the order and count of the records are the same between your textBoxCodeContainer and the database.

*What is the relation between a textbox and a row. How do you know what textbox links to which row?*

I could give you a push in the right direction, if you show me some more code (like where/how is textBoxCodeContainer defined)

---

UPDATE:

---

I made some code the read and manipulate your database, this is **not** tested since i don't have any database here.

I would create these classes, 1 is a data class `Product` and one is a Handler class `ProductHandler`.

The data class only contains the data (not in presentation format) The data handler knows how to read and write them.

```
    public class Product
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductHandler
    {
        public ProductHandler(string connectionString)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public bool AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            return AddProducts(new Product[] { product }) > 0;
        }
        public int AddProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
        {
            int rowsInserted = 0;

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string query = "INSERT INTO [Seranne] (Code, Description, Quantity) VALUES(@Code, @Description, @Quantity)";

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", OleDbType.Integer);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Description", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", OleDbType.Integer);

                    foreach (var product in products)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = product.Code;
                        cmd.Parameters["Description"].Value = product.Description;
                        cmd.Parameters["Quantity"].Value = product.Quantity;

                        rowsInserted += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            return rowsInserted;
        }

        public bool UpdateProduct(Product product)
        {
            return UpdateProducts(new Product[] { product }) > 0;
        }
        public int UpdateProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
        {
            int rowsUpdated = 0;

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string query = "UPDATE [Seranne] SET Description = @Description, Quantity = @Quantity WHERE [Code] == @Code)";

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", OleDbType.Integer);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Description", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", OleDbType.Integer);

                    foreach (var product in products)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = product.Code;
                        cmd.Parameters["Description"].Value = product.Description;
                        cmd.Parameters["Quantity"].Value = product.Quantity;

                        rowsUpdated += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            return rowsUpdated;
        }

        public bool DeleteProduct(Product product)
        {
            return DeleteProducts(new int[] { productCode }) > 0;
        }
        public int DeleteProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string productCodeStr = string.Join(", ", products.Select(item => item.Code));
                string query = string.Format("DELETE FROM [Seranne] WHERE [Code] in ({0})", productCodeStr);

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    int rowsDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return rowsDeleted;
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> ReadAllProducts()
        {
            List<Product> result = new List<Product>();

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Code], [Description], [Quantity] FROM [Seranne]", conn))
                using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    while (dReader.Read())
                    {
                        Product product = new Product();
                        product.Code = Convert.ToInt32(dReader["Code"]);
                        product.Description = Convert.ToString(dReader["Description"]);
                        product.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dReader["Quantity"]);
                        result.Add(product);
                    }
            }

            return result;
        }

        public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }
    }
```

---

Some example code:

```
    ProductHandler _productHandler = new ProductHandler("connectionstring here or from config");

    public void Example()
    {
        _productList.Clear();
        _productList.AddRange(_productHandler.ReadAllProducts());

        // displaying
        foreach (var product in _productList)
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("code: {0}, description: {1}, quantity: {2}", product.Code, product.Description, product.Quantity);

        // updating
        var selectedProduct = _productList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Code == 15);
        if(selectedProduct!= null)
        {
            selectedProduct.Quantity = 50;
            _productHandler.UpdateProduct(selectedProduct);
        }

        // deleting
        _productHandler.DeleteProducts(_productList.Where(item => item.Quantity < 5));
    }
```

---

How to link the textboxes to the right product:

I would create a UserControl that contains a Product property and the TextBoxes and handles when textbox_changed events occurs. Those event handlers manipulate the Product instance.

You only generate 16 controls and bind a product to it. When you press a button, you only need to save the changed products.

Comment: I'm still stuck on why you're doing the If statement there, why should the quantity be bigger than the stored quantity?

Comment: Hi @Jeroen van Langen, thanks for replying my question. The system will recognized by the time that user entering the `Product Code`, `Product Code` is the first thing that user must do, in order to displaying all the datas including the price and it refers to the which `Product Code`. So, all the datas and price are displayed based on the `Product Code`

I will show you some more code, please refer to the question again. Thank you

And, i don't get it what do you mean in your answer at the number 4.

Comment: i did that before i know that the value of `textBoxQuantityContainer` can be set to the maximum value. Just ignore it. And i already knew that i can set the maximum value, so just know i delete it that statement "quantity bigger than the stored quantity". Thanks

Comment: I would advise to separate the data and presentation by busyness objects. Now you are refering to controls within you sql update methods. I can give you an example if you like. This will also makes it easier to understand whats happening.

Comment: Sure, that will be better. Since, i don't know how to solve this.

Comment: you said that i don't need the reader when updating the data. But, inside `newVal` variable, i do have the statement where i have to use the reader.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen van Langen, i will try those code from you later.

Comment: I recomment, keep your data layer (database queries) / gui layer (textboxes) separated, see here some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800946/presentation-business-and-data-layer and here: http://systems-analysis.net/architecture/introduction.html

Comment: Hai @Jeroen van Langen: i have found this on website that is your code was the best practice. I will follow that. Thanks a bunch! But, i am sorry, because your example is not what i want, so i'm not going to use it. and i just wondering this code: `var selectedProduct = _productList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Code == 15);` i am not sure if i am understand this. And also just want to let you know, i am doing the update quantity right now, the one that i had problem.

Comment: This code is selecting the first item from the list, if it hasn't got any item, it will return default(T) where T is the type in your List<T>. For classes it is null. The `var` will be replaced during compiling for the type the `FirstOrDefault` returns. The code i gave you is just for example how to separate sql code and gui code. Maybee someone else may have a use for it. Good luck

Comment: Hai @Jeroen van Langen, the program was successful update to the database with the correct value. But, like you said in the question "How do you know what textbox links to the which row", this happen when the program was successful update and my thought was incorrect. I apologize. Even though i entered the different value in each "Product Code", and update it, the program just recognized the first entered "Product Code" same goes with the value and update it to the database and the second value in the database, same with the first. Even though it is not same value when i modify manually.

Comment: In your example you're trying to update all rows with one statement, split them up into multiple statements. You could create e method that update one row and call that in a for loop.

Comment: Hai @Jeroen van Langen: i already did what you suggest to me, but the database only read on first "Quantity" row that has been entered, and apply it to all rows, even though they are different "Quantity", but the value after "Update" are same with the first "Quantity" row

Comment: If you use `string query = "SELECT [Quantity], [Description], [Price] FROM [Seranne] WHERE [Code] IN (";` The `SET [Quantity]=?` will be applied to all records that are selected in the where clause. Use `WHERE [Code] = @Code` instead.

Comment: Hai @Jeroen van Langen: i make a new thread on my problem. Could you please help me again? Thank you very much.. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555155/update-to-the-database-error-when-enter-more-than-1-value